# How to convert data in a file to a nested hash or an array of hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a file in the following format. I have about 100 records starting from Record 1 in the file. Here are few records from the file:

```
Record 1:

[record   
  acct_num      "11111111"  
  trxn_dt       "20140822"   
  post_dt       "20140822"  
  trxn_amt      "33.4"  
  trxn_cat      "RCI"  
  trxn_cat_desc "ABCD"]

Record 2:

[record  
  acct_num      "44444444"  
  trxn_dt       "20140819"  
  post_dt       "20140822"  
  trxn_amt      "183.75"  
  trxn_cat      "ACI"  
  trxn_cat_desc "DEFG"]
```

I want to convert the data in this file into a nested hash or a array of hashes so that I can perform assertions. I want a nested hash like:

```
{
  {
    acct_num => "11111111",
    trxn_dt => "20140822",
    post_dt => "20140822",
    trxn_amt => "33.4",
    trxn_cat => "RCI",
    trxn_cat_desc => "ABCD"
  },
  {
    acct_num => "44444444",
    trxn_dt => "20140819",
    post_dt => "20140822",
    trxn_amt => "183.75",
    trxn_cat => "ACI",
    trxn_cat_desc => "DEFG"
  }
}
```

Any pointers will be helpful.

My bad. I didn't upload the code which I have tried. Thanks for letting me know. I'm new to ruby and this is what I have tried so far:

```
temp_file_output = File.open('file.txt', 'r')                                                     
  temp_file_output.readlines.each do |line|                                                 
    if line.match(/record/)                                                                        
      new_line = line.next                                             
    key, value = new_line.chomp.split(/"/)      
    file_read_hash[key] = value  
    end  
  end
```

Ok so today I tried to revisit my code and made the below changes.I was able to write the first element into a hash. Still figuring out on how to include the remaining elements into the hash. Any pointers/suggestions? Here's my code:

```
file_read_hash = {}  
   temp_file_output = File.open('sample.txt', 'r')  
   while !temp_file_output.eof?  
      line = temp_file_output.readline  
      if line.include?("record")  
        new_line = temp_file_output.readline.next  
          key,value = new_line.chomp.split(/"/)  
          file_read_hash[key.strip] = value  
          break if line.include?("]")  
        end  
      end  
   puts file_read_hash
```

Output: {"rtr_acct_num"=>"44444444"}

Comment: Your expected "hash" is invalid. It is impossible to get such object in Ruby.

Comment: Also, what are the values of `acct_num`, etc. in your expected "hash"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's customary to provide a minimal example of the code you've written, and explain why it's not accomplishing the job and what you think is the problem. Without that it looks like you want us to write the code for you, which we don't do.

Comment: Thanks for lettine me know. My bad, I didn't upload what I have tried in the 1st place. I have now modified my question and included what I had tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file_read_hash = {}   
  file_read_hash_collect = {}  
   @file_read_array = []  
    File.foreach('sample.txt') do |line|  
    next if line.include?("Record") or line.empty?  
     next if line.include?("[record")  
      key,value = line.chomp.split(/"/)  
      key = key.to_s.strip  
      value = value.to_s.strip  
      file_read_hash[key] = value  
    file_read_hash_collect = file_read_hash.delete_if{|k,v|k.blank? and  v.blank?} 
   if line.include?("]")  
      @file_read_array.push(file_read_hash_collect)  
      file_read_hash = {}  
      file_read_hash_collect = {}
  end
end
puts @file_read_array
```

Comment: I was able to read all the contents of the file into an array of hashes.

Answer (score 0):

To have valid Ruby objects you need something like this:

```
records = [
  [ [:acct_num,      "11111111"],  
    [:trxn_dt,       "20140822"],   
    [:trxn_cat_desc, "ABCD"]
  ],
  [ [:acct_num,      "44444444"],
    [:trxn_dt,       "20140819"],  
    [:trxn_cat_desc, "DEFG"]
  ]
]  

records.map(&:to_h)
  #=> [{:acct_num=>"11111111",
  #     :trxn_dt=>"20140822",
  #     :trxn_cat_desc=>"ABCD"},
  #    {:acct_num=>"44444444",
  #     :trxn_dt=>"20140819",
  #     :trxn_cat_desc=>"DEFG"}]
```

You can think of `map(&:to_h)` as being shorthand for:

```
records.map { |a| a.to_h }
```

We were given [Array#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) in Ruby v2.0. For earlier versions, use the class method [Hash::[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D):

```
records.map { |a| Hash[a] }
```

Comment: OK.  You're trying to get some obscure badge? ;)

Comment: No, just cancelling @sawa's upvote: `10 - 5*2 #=> 0`. Four to go.

Comment: To explain the above comments, I initially prefaced my answer with, "
This is an extended comment. No upvotes or checkmark, please." That was edited out by @halfer, which is OK by me.